# Flex: How to handle focusouthandler only to the component but not to the children inside the component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I want to handle the focus out Handler only to the component which i want to listen but not to the children inside to that component. 
Example i have a vgroup inside that vgroup container i have UI Controls like TextInput, TextArea, ComboBox and i want to listen focus out for VGroup so i kept focusoutHandler for VGroup but when i change the focus from textinput to textarea or combobox focusoutHandler is getting called.How to give focusOut only for VGroup.

```
<s:VGroup id="vGroup" focusOut = vGroupFocusOutHandler(event)>
   <s:TextInput />
   <s:TextArea/>
   <s:ComboBox/>  
<s:VGroup/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the object the user is focusing into is not a child (directly or indirectly) of the VGroup. If it *is* a child we don't do anything; if it's not, we do what has to be done.

Here's how:

```
<s:VGroup id="vGroup" focusOut="handleFocusOut(event)">
    <s:TextInput />
    <s:TextArea />
    <s:ComboBox />  
</s:VGroup>
```

.

```
private function handleFocusOut(event:FocusEvent):void {
    //only do something if we focus out of vGroup
    if (!isInVGroup(event.relatedObject)) {
        trace(event);
    }
}

private function isInVGroup(el:InteractiveObject):Boolean {
    if (!el || !el.parent) return false;

    var parent:DisplayObjectContainer = el.parent;
    while (parent != vGroup && parent != stage) {
        parent = parent.parent;
    }

    return parent == vGroup;
}
```

The `relatedObject` property is the element the user focuses into.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer RIAstar here the problem is i have so many controls as well as other containers inside that vgroup there are dynamically added and its very hard to add focusout to each and every control so is there any solution for this.

Comment: @Trinu Good remark! I've updated my answer and made it more elegant (thanks to your comment).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in event handler code:

```
private function handleFocusOut(event:FocusEvent):void {
    //only do something if we focus out of vGroup
    if (!this.contains(event.relatedObject)) {
        trace(event);
    }
}
```